# SQL &apos; --> ' replacement

Tags: sql

I have dynamic table so I need to execute this query

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'select x, y from exTable where z like 'example' '   

EXEC (@SQL)
```

I have problem becouse 'example' can't be added to @sql variable.

I try to add &apos ;example&apos ; but it does not work.

Any suggestion how can I change from  &apos ; -->  '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quote quotes in SQL by an extra quote:

```
SET @SQL = 'select x, y from exTable where z like ''example'' '
```